# Working with multidimensional Arrays - Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Hi working on a uni exercise and need to create a multidimensional array to hold some strings. But i'm a bit confused on how to access / declare the variables because how do i make the program know when i'm assigning variables which dimension i'm referring to?  The end goal is create a 3 by 3 array but i assume the logic is the same as 2 by 2 but i just need to know how to access the arrays i want to.
Thanks in advance :)

```
    String[][] Albums = new String[5][10];
    String song1,song2,song3;
    String album1,album2,album3;
    album1 = "Best classic hits";
    album2 = "Best pop hits";
    album3 = "Best rock hits";
    song1 = "Greatest funk song";
    song2 = "Greatest pop song";
    song3 = "Greatest rock song";
    Albums[0][0] = album1;  
    Albums[1][0] = album2;
    Albums[2][0] = album3;
```

Comment: *The end goal is create a 3 by 3 array* Well as of now you are declaring a `5` by `10` `Array

Comment: *"i just need to know how to access the arrays i want to"* You're already accessing the arrays: `Albums[0][0]` --- It is unclear what is stopping you from doing what you want.

Comment: Because when i say Albums[0][0] = album1 and Albums[0][0] = song1  one of these is obviously getting overwritten..  What im trying to achieve in the end is, Albums[0][0] =  "Best Classic hits" , "Greatest Funk Song".. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: You need to make `album1` a `String[]` (as it should be an array of songs). You could then do `album1[0] = "First Song";`, then do `Albums[0] = album1;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are creating a 5x10 array, you want to access the array to print the elements ? just create a nested for loop

like this

```
        for(i=0;i<=2;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<=2;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(Number[i][j]+"\t");
            }
         }
```

Edit reading your comment is this what you want ?

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String[][] Album = {
            {"Best classic hits ", "Best pop hits ", "Best rock hits "},
            {"Greatest funk song" , "Greatest pop song" , "Greatest rock song"}
    };


    System.out.println(Album[0][0] + Album[1][0]);
    System.out.println(Album[0][1] + Album[1][1]);
    System.out.println(Album[0][2] + Album[1][2]);

}
```

Comment: Yeap that was exactly it! :) I didnt realise that multidimensional arrays linked as one with their indexing. I looked it as more of a directory style i suppose as in a example of Album[0][0] Look into the first array at index 0, within that array is a sub-array which elements start from 0

Comment: Aight mate glad that I helped !

Answer (score 0):

First correct this:

```
// To make the size 3 by 3
String[][] Albums = new String[3][3];
```

Then you can access each element like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Albums.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < Albums[i].length; j++ ) {
        System.out.println(Albums[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry i may have worded my question badly. I know how i can loop through it like the way you described but im having trouble actually setting the elements of the array. When i say Albums[0][0] = albumName and then Albums[0][0] = songName, one of these is obviously being overwritten with whatever is second.Unless im just mistaken and how this is set up is 2 completely seperate arrays compared to what i want which is An array with a sub array of sorts?

Answer (score 0):

Start by initializing the array to the desired size. Here you said you needed 3x3, so I assume the array looks like this:

```
[[album, song0, song1], 
[album, song0, song1], 
[album, song0, song1]]
```

Because representing an *object (eg `(album, song0, song1)`)* by array is prone to error, I would suggest creating helper methods to manage the data structure access. These methods ensure you don't override the wrong array entry by mistake.

```
static void setData(String[] data, String album, String song0, String song1) {
    setAlbum(data, album);
    setSong0(data, song0);
    setSong1(data, song1);
}

static String getAlbum(String[] data) {
    return data[0];
}
static void setAlbum(String[] data, String album) {
    data[0] = album;
}

static String getSong0(String[] data) {
    return data[1];
}
static void setSong0(String[] data, String song0) {
    data[1] = song0;
}

static String getSong1(String[] data) {
    return data[2];
}
static void setSong1(String[] data, String song1) {
    data[2] = song1;
}
...

String[][] data = new String[3][3];
setData(data[0], "album 0", "album 0 song 0", "album 0 song 1");
setData(data[1], "album 1", "album 1 song 0", "album 1 song 1");
setData(data[2], "album 2", "album 2 song 0", "album 2 song 1");
```